# Creating new activity in android

Tags: android

```
    happyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent response = new Intent(this, UserResponse.class);
            startActivity(response);

        };


    });
```

There's an error in the line (this, UserResponse.class);
even after I created a new class called UserResponse.

Comment: What is the IDE telling you the error is? If you hover over the content that is marked with a red squiggly underline (or hover over the error icon in the gutter on the left), it will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Problem is in *this*, you are calling it from *Button* instance, change it from **ClassName.this**

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
Intent response = new Intent(this, UserResponse.class);
```

To

```
Intent response = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserResponse.class);
```

Replace the `MainActivity` by the name of your current activity (current.. not target activity)

Answer (score 2):

If you had created the class manually, Check for two things:

1. `UserResponse` class extends `Activity`
2. The Activity is included in the Manifest

It should be something like this

```
<activity 
    android:name="UserResponse" 
    android:label="@string/User_Response">
</activity>
```

Also change the intent as Guilherme P has suggested

Answer (score 0):

Its because you use .this in an onClicklistener change it to getApplicaton()